# Disabling form inputs/selects/etc on.submit, data is not sent to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can i disable inputs/selects/file inputs etc on submit event if the target of the form is an iframe?

Here's the [link](http://sandbox.emiliocarrino.it/test_01.php) of a "working" example of the issue i'm having.

Here you can see the code.

```
<?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['iframe'])) {
                if (isset($_POST['name_1'])) {
                        echo 'POST PIENO<br />';
                } else {
                        echo 'POST VUOTO<br />';       
                }
                echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
                die();
        }
?>
<html>
        <head>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
                <script>
                        function disableOnSubmit() {
                                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                                $('#button2').attr('disabled', false);
                                $('#form').submit(function(e){
                                        $(this).find('input').attr('disabled', true);
                                });
                        }
                        function enableOnSubmit() {
                                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                                $('#button1').attr('disabled', false);
                                $('#form').find('input').attr('disabled', false);
                                $('#form').unbind();
                        }
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('#button1').click(disableOnSubmit);
                                $('#button2').click(enableOnSubmit);
                        });
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <input type="button" id="button1" value="Disabled on Submit" />
                <input type="button" id="button2" disabled value="Enabled on Submit" />
                <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?iframe" method="post" id="form" target="iframe">
                        <input type="text" name="name_1" value="value_1" />
                        <input type="text" name="name_2" value="value_2" />
                        <input type="text" name="name_3" value="value_3" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="iframe" value="true" />
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                </form>
                <iframe src="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?iframe" name="iframe" />
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If inputs are disabled as per the HTTP specification the data will not form part of the POST/GET request. Instead you are probably looking for the `readonly` attribute -- this will disable the inputs and still post the data.

**17.12** Disabled and read-only controls: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

> In this example, the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.

```
<INPUT disabled name="fred" value="stone">
```

---

**Edit**

Your submit event is firing BEFORE the form is submitted, inside that function your disabling the inputs which means once it's exited that function, and when it goes to submit, those inputs are disabled therefore the data is not sent.

There is not a simple way to detect when a form is submitted (aside from using ajax and a `complete` event handler) -- however you could simulate this by listening to the `load` event on the iframe, and then disable the parents input elements.

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    $(this.ownerDocument.body).find('input').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

However if your trying to stop multiple submissions, this won't help as your form submit request would have already been handled by the time the `load` event fires.

If the above is your goal, I would suggest to just disable the submit button once the form is submitted (and maybe add a loading icon to show to the user something is happening etc).

Comment: the question is not about what "disabled" stands for, but how can i disable all inputs after i submitted the form

Comment: @razorxan your title is misleading then, you mention as part of the title "data is not sent to an iframe"

Comment: the title says Disabling form inputs/selects/etc ON SUBMIT (read on submit) , data is not sent to an iframe

PS: Read (ON SUBMIT)

Comment: I think you mean to say: How to disable form inputs/selects/etc AFTER submit of data -- your title is currently showing the opposite of what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Also the answer I provided is part of your issue, the submit event is firing BEFORE the form is submitted, inside that function your disabling the buttons which means once it's exited that function, and when it goes to submit, those inputs are disabled therefore the data is not sent.

Comment: is there an "aftersubmit" event then? i really think you anderstood me very well since the beginning and you're just not helping me